# How to add edit button in content type?

Tags: views, 7

I am new to drupal and I was adding a button for editing the data from database.
but when I am adding edit button using add content type then this error message is showing to me.Please help me to guide how to add buttons and relate them to database.

Comment: Provide more information. What errors you getting and what you want to do? It is unclear for another person.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: edit_hidden in button_field_field_widget_form() (line 295 of C:\wamp\www\drupal\sites\all\modules\button_field\button_field.module) error message is this

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to add the edit button in a node. well, first you need to get the node ID, create `template.php` and add this function :

```
function YOUR-THEME_preprocess_node(&$variables)
{
    if (isset($variables['node'])) 
    {
         $variables['id'] = $variables['node']->nid;
    }
}
```

in this way the node id will be saved in the `$id` variable inside the node template file. if you want to use the default `node.tpl.php` copy this file from `modules/system/node.tpl.php`. now add this code where ever you want in the new copied `node.tpl.php`

```
<?php
    global $base_url;
?>
<a href="<?php print $base_url;?>/node/<?php print $id;?>/edit">Edit the Content! </a>
```

if you suggest any theme hook (theme the node page) no difference does it make, use the above code, the link always will be

```
"<?php print $base_url;?>/node/<?php print $id;?>/edit"
```

Good luck